# why are NONE of my INSERT queries working now?

Tags: mysql, lamp, database

i moved my site to a new machine and now none of the INSERT statements are working. users are able to log in, view their friends list, search for other users, and delete friends/content from their stream, but no one is able now to send friend requests, new users arent being registered, and no new content is being able to be added. 
does anyone have any idea why none of the INSERT statements are working anymore?

this site is on running on a lamp server... i initially noticed that there was a problem posting new content, and i spent a long time trying to figure what could have happened to the posting script and why it wasnt anylonger working, then i realized all of the other problems and that they are all INSERT statements

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: PS. The interesting detail is that you moved things to another machine. So is there a dependency between the database and the old machine? Some ODBC connection maybe??

Comment: related because the only machine was a windows machine, and now is running on a ubuntu machine, well thats why i asked it here anyway

Comment: You gave no details at all about the steps taken during the move, so its very difficult to imagine what the problem is. I  can only advise you to check the connection to the database and whether any rules are in place that only allowes updates to the database from the windows machine.

Comment: My first question would be: can you manually perform insertions from the *same machine* using the *same* credentials as the application uses? (Credentials being: database name, database user, password, and server name)

Comment: I can perform all queries from the command line, it's only, it seems, INSERT statements used with mysqli_query.

Comment: I have seen this in applications that used `mysqli` and didn't use a `mysqli_commit()` statement at the end of the program. You can very well do `SELECT`s but `INSERT`s don't work. Can you insert a `mysqli_commit()` statement somewhere and see if this makes a difference?